# LINQ Custom OrderLine Fields in uCommerce

Tags: linq, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I'm trying to count how many orderlines (ol) that have the custom field "distributedOrderLineId" equal to the orderline id of the current iteration.

The thing is, that not every orderline has this custom field defined. How can I make LINQ skip the orderlines with an undefined custom field instead of throwing an error.

Please refer to the code below.

```
var distributionsLeft = ol.Quantity - 1 - PurchaseOrder.All().Where(y => int.Parse(y["distributedOrderLineId"]) == ol.Id).Count();
```

Best regards,
Brinck10

**EDIT**

I've tried the following piece of code using *any*:

```
PurchaseOrder.All().Where(y => y.OrderProperties.Any(z=>z.Key=="distributedOrderLineId")).Where(a=>a["distributedOrderLineId"]==ol.OrderLineId.ToString()).Count();
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The error I get on the stack trace is:

```
[NotSupportedException: System.String get_Item(System.String)]
   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression) +206
```

**EDIT END**

Comment: Specify what is the type of y? Or from what generic IEnumerable<T> PurchaseOrder is derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've get what you want. I've simulated your `PurchaseOrder` with an array of dictionaries and I suppose, that formal parameter `y` in your lambda expression is derived from `IDictionary`, because I can see such expression `y["distributedOrderLineId"]`. Please correct me if I'm wrong in my assumptions.
The solution is to check whether key is set by calling `order.ContainsKey("id")`. You can see the example below

```
var firstItem = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"id", "11"}};
var secondItem = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"id", "12"}};
var thirdItem = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // id is not set, as distributedOrderLineId in your example
var fourthItem = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"id", "14"}};

var PurchaseOrder = new [] {firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem, fourthItem};
var quantity = 4;
var orderID = 12;
var distributionsLeft = quantity - 1 - PurchaseOrder.Where(order => order.ContainsKey("id") && int.Parse(order["id"]) == orderID).Count();

Console.WriteLine (distributionsLeft);
```

**Edit:**
Could you please try to use next query, just to see if it work? We can then try to do some optimizations if it works fine.

```
PurchaseOrder.Where(y => y.OrderProperties.Any(z => z.Key == "distributedOrderLineId"))
             .ToList()
             .Where(y => y["distributedOrderLineId"] == ol.OrderLineId.ToString())
             .Count();
```

**Optimized version**: I've tried to optimize version given above from performance and readability points of view, but note - I cold be wrong, because I haven't run that query. I've changed it only by analyzing uCommerce documentation regarding [OrderLine](http://www.ucommerce.dk/docs/html/T_UCommerce_EntitiesV2_OrderLine.htm) and [OrderProperty](http://www.ucommerce.dk/docs/html/T_UCommerce_EntitiesV2_OrderProperty.htm). Also note, that I've used different names for formal parameters in lambdas - just to get rid of mess with y and z.

```
string orderLineId = ol.OrderLineId.ToString();
PurchaseOrder
    .Count(order => order.OrderProperties.Any(property => property.Key == "distributedOrderLineId" && property.Value == orderLineId));
```

Comment: Ilya, you understand what I opt for, however, the custom field is a part of the **OrderLine** class (reference: http://www.ucommerce.dk/docs/html/T_UCommerce_EntitiesV2_OrderLine.htm) and does not contain the method **ContainsKey**. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What does it return or do, if you pass y["distributedOrderLineId"] and this id is not set?

Comment: The problem is, that I haven't even created the distributedOrderLineId custom field in many of the orderlines. I want to check in the same where clause, if such field exists and if it does then compare the identities.

Comment: Can you please try to use query, given after "edit" in the answer? Please respond if it works or not? It's pity, I cant reproduce your situation in my machine, so I just try to deduce what the problem is

Comment: Ilya, the code you wrote under edit worked! Can we then optimize it?

Comment: Do we have to? I've tried to change query to more optimal solution, but note - it could not work. I don't like to give such answers, because the risk of being wrong is too high, but I've tried to optimize in both performance and readability. Feel free to respond to me if the query under section 'optimized version' worked. By the way - Merry Christmas)

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't use count in the beginning. I rephrased your code to the following working peace `PurchaseOrder.All().Where(y => y.OrderProperties.Any(z => z.Key == "distributedOrderLineId")).ToList().Where(a => a["distributedOrderLineId"] == ol.OrderLineId.ToString()).Count()`

Comment: Thanks for all your help and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a specific key/value combo like so:

```
bool anyLinesWithKeyValue = purchaseOrder.OrderLines.Any(x => x.OrderProperties.Any(y => y.Key == "distributedOrderLineId" && y.Value == "someValue"));
```

That'll just give you a "yay" or "nay" on whether there are any actual lines that has that combo. If you need the order lines for something just replace "Any" with "Where".

Hope this helps.